# Как сравнить все элементы списка друг с другом?

Tags: python

Изначально есть список со строками.

Нужно проверить, является ли хоть одна строка подстрокой второй (то есть начинается ли с нее эта строка)

```
spisok = ['a', 'b', 'cd', 'are']
```

Программа должна вывести **a** и **are**, т.к. **a** является подстрокой **are** (are начинается с **a**)

Вопрос:
Как в цикле пройтись по КАЖДОМУ элементу списка? Например текущий со следующим можно сравнить с помощью цикла

```
for i in range(len(spisok)):
    if spisok[i].startsith(spisok[i+1]):
        ...
```

Но как сравнить ВСЕ элементы друг с другом?

Comment: Список как-нибудь отсортирован*

Comment: Список не отсортирован, элементы расположены рандомно

Comment: так отсортируйте :)  и сравнивайте соседей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу и я свой вариант, поскольку я не уверен, что "подстрока" - это именно "начинается с", это может быть и "входит". Ну и, кроме того, я не люблю использование `range` без нужды, поэтому хочу привести решение без него.

```
spisok = ['a', 'b', 'cd', 'are']

for i, word1 in enumerate(spisok):
    for word2 in spisok[i + 1:]:
        if word1 in word2 or word2 in word1:
            print(word1, word2)
```

Comment: Там же написанно: `are начинается с a`

Comment: @user363756 Но там же написано и "является подстрокой", что не одно и то же.

Comment: Не любите `range`, который в памяти по сути держит всего 3 значения, зато на каждой итерации создаёте копию подписка списка :)

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Но это копия не самих объектов, а копия ссылок на объекты. По которым нам всё-равно надо пройтись во время цикла. Так что оверхед тут небольшой, зато всё красиво и прозрачно :)

Comment: @CrazyElf При взятии среза как раз-таки копируются объекты.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Slicing lists does not generate copies of the objects in the list; it just copies the references to them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131563/8324991

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Хотя оверхед на создание нового списка всё-равно есть, это да (

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, Вы правы. Я перепутал ссылки на элементы списка и ссылку на сам список.

Answer (score 5):

```
spisok = ['a', 'b', 'cd', 'are']

for word1 in spisok:
    for word2 in spisok:
        if word1 != word2 and word1.startswith(word2):
            print(word1, word2)
# выведет: are a
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(len(spisok)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(spisok)):
        if spisok[i] in spisok[j]:
            print(spisok[i])
            print(spisok[j])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

spisok = ['a', 'b', 'cd', 'are', 'all', 'bb']

b = list(itertools.combinations(spisok, 2))
res = [x for x in b if x[0] in x[1]]
```

тогда res будет:

```
[('a', 'are'), ('a', 'all'), ('b', 'bb')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Как сравнить ВСЕ элементы друг с другом?
Например, есть два списка.

```
lst_1 = [2,4,8,16,12]
lst_2 = [4,6,12,1,8]
```

Создаем пустой список. Создаем цикл для первого списка. Добавляем условие: если i есть во втором списке то добавляем его в третий список.

```
lst_3 = [] 

for i in lst_1:  
    if i in lst_2:  
        lst_3.append(i) 
print(lst_3)
```

Результат: [4,12,8]

Таким образом, программа сравнит все элементы в двух списках и соберёт из них третий, в котором есть одинаковые для двух списков элементы.
point it's a button space )
Точки это отступы.
the methods above are more complicated

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).