# цикл. обход каждого элемента и сравнение между собой

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

Есть список:

```
m = ['привет', 'привет я толик','городе москва','привет я толик живу и учусь в городе москва','я толик','учусь','живу']
```

нужно сравнить каждый элемент МЕЖДУ СОБОЙ на вхождение и оставить в итоге только 'привет я толик живу и учусь в городе москва' - т.к все остальные элементы входят в эту строку.

Может быть и не через цикл это можно делать, но идеи(решение есть) пока только через него. Мб у кого есть ещё идеи как можно по другому сделать?

Т.к мой вопрос был не очень понятен, и возникли недопонимания: - я скинула код, соответственно он уже у меня был решен и мне не нужно было решение, мне нужна была ИДЕЯ.

Вот собственно решение, если кто-то с этим столкнулся.

```
hg = []
for i in m:
    for k in m:
        if i in k:
            if i == k:
                continue
            else:
                hg.append(i)
        else: continue
    [item for item in m if item not in hg]
```

Comment: с чем сравнивать элементы то? Что вам мешает сразу вывести нужный элемент?

Comment: Мешает то, что мне нужно найти вхождение, а представьте что у меня есть список, где среди этих элементов есть строка которая не входит в ту которая мне нужна. Например: [ я люблю, я люблю бананы, я люблю бананы и перец, школа 21, сош 23 школа 21] и в итоге если искать вхождения и получать итог то - [сош 23 школа 21, я люблю бананы и перец]

Comment: @wanna_feel в вопросе как раз я сразу после вопроса tomato-magnet-regulato проставилось уточнение. А при чем тут делать за меня, просто подскажите как можно это сделать, для этого и создан этот сайт, что бы помочь новичкам, если нет желания - то и зачем ставить -1? причем тут фриланс, я что на этой задачке из интернета взятой деньги делаю?

Comment: @Lit, ты хочешь готовый код который делает твою задачу, покажи что ты делал, ошибку. На фрилансе делают готовый код.

Answer (score 1):

Код не даю, код вы сами должны написать. Но если я правильно понял суть:

- перебираете в цикле элементы списка, используя их индекс
- для каждого их них пробегаете по **остальным** элементам списка и проверяете, что они в этот элемент входят
- если условие выполнилось, добавляете этот элемент в выходной список

Всё, что вам нужно - знание `range`, `for`, `if`, `in`, то есть базовые вещи в питоне. Ну и `break` ещё. Ну и основы работы со списками - создание, добавление.

Answer (score 1):

По итогу вот код, может быть кому-то пригодится:

```
hg = []
for i in m:
    for k in m:
        if i in k:
            if i == k:
                continue
            else:
                hg.append(i)
        else: continue

[item for item in m if item not in hg]
```

Comment: После некторого опыта, вернитесь к этому коду. Может он и работает сейчас, но есть более лаконичные и понятные решения в духе python

Comment: для добавления кода в ваш вопрос, вы можете просто под вашим вопросом кликнуть на править, и дополнить, если это требуется, не обязательно отправлять правку или дополнение в ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое, я все замечания и предложения учту) Код попробую улучшить, позже напишу!

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194596/209304) пример как воспользоваться сравнением в списке. Главная идея есть, вам только условие заменить